# Get specific content from XML Fragment

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

The text file contains attributes such as

```
    <file loc="NEEDTHIS" id="140359"/>
    <file loc="NEEDTHIS2" id="137406"/>
    <file loc="NEEDTHIS3" id="137545"/>
```

How do I get just the file locations and store it in a **string array**?

Expected output:

```
    NEEDTHIS
    NEEDTHIS2
    NEEDTHIS3
```

Comment: Do you want to store it in **one** concatenated string or an array of strings? Please show the expected output.

Comment: This is not an XML document. It is a fragment. Are you sure this is the entire document?

Comment: @Yuck I need it in an array, edited OP.

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes this is just a fragment. I don't want to spam with unnecessary code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Very small hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel.aspx

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know how to do this in PHP, but I'm learning how to do it in C#, in PHP it is very simple no need for XML reader, I'm sure its the same with C# too surely?

Comment: PHP is not an example of a good programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) can do it:

```
var paths = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
                     .Descendants("file")
                     .Select(n => n.Attribute("loc").Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", paths));
```

Broken down into a foreach loop:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var paths = new List<string>();
foreach (var file in doc.Descendants("file"))
    paths.Add(file.Attribute("loc").Value); // or just Console.WriteLine(file.Attribute("loc").Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", paths));
```

Comment: This is working nicely but the only problem is its all in one line, how to use the "foreach" statement here correctly?

Comment: There's an example of a foreach loop for you.

Comment: You could also do `.ToArray()` at the end of the first query to put the strings into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Load the file into an `XDocument` object and then use LINQ to pull out the `loc` attribute from each `file` element, like this:

```
var doc = new XDocument();
doc.Load("path to your XML file");

var files = from file in doc.Descendants("file")
            select (string)service.Element("loc");
```

Comment: Yes, thank you John Saunders. Updated answer.